# New to Vue, stuck on global variable

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js

I'm trying to make a filtered list in Native Vue. I'm compiling and running for Android.

```
export default {
  components: { card },
  data: 
  { 
    search: 'An', 
    level: "", 
  },
  computed: {
    searchInLowerCase() 
    {
      return this.search.toLowerCase().trim().toString();
    },
    filteredList()
    {
      return cards.filter((el) =>
      {
        return el.Name.toLowerCase().includes("an"); //this one works
        return el.Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchInLowerCase); // This doesn't work
        return el.Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search);//same
      })
    }
```

The "this variable" works under the filteredList function, but not under the short hand filter function. Under this function the This variables are undefined.
Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Erik

Comment: ps. im not returning 3 times(its normal for a function to stop after 1 return).
In my code its a single return with which i am testing

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're in a different scope at this point.
You can keep a reference to `this` though.

```js
filteredList() {
  const vm = this; // obviously doesn't have to be called vm. Choose whatever name you like
  return cards.filter((el) => // <-- Your `this`-scope breaks here
  {
    return el.Name.toLowerCase().includes("an"); //this one works
    return el.Name.toLowerCase().includes(vm.searchInLowerCase); <-- use reference here
    return el.Name.toLowerCase().includes(vm.search); <-- and here
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i thought this.search was a global and should be reached throughout the code.